# How to add a 'Sort By' dropdown to sort a list in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, sorting, filtering

I've got a pretty straight forward setup.

Trying to display a list of users with a search box at the top (for actively filtering the search results).

If I use *just that* the page works and displays fine.

I'm trying to add in an additional dropdown to pick an attribute to sort by (and hopefully add in another dropdown to indicate ascending/descending once I get the first dropdown working).

My current code (with a non-working version of the sort) looks like this:

```
    <div id="app">
        <section class="mb-3">
            <div class="container">
                <h2>Person Search</h2>
                <h3>
                    <small class="text-muted">Filter people based on the name, location or job</small>
                </h3>
                <h3>
                    <small class="text-muted">
                        Examples: “Jane Doe”, “ABC Building”, or “Math”
                    </small>
                </h3>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="search_term" placeholder="Begin typing to filter by name, location or job...">
                <!-- THIS WOULD CAUSE THE LIST TO FILTER ALPHABETICALLY BY SELECTED ATTRIBUTE -->
                <select id="sortFilterSelect" name="sort_filter" v-model="sort_filter">
                    <option value="">Sort By...</option>
                    <option value="first_name">First Name</option>
                    <option value="last_name">Last Name</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section>
            <div class="container">
                <h3>People List : ([[ people_count ]] People)</h3>
                <!-- I ADDED 'sortedPeople' HERE - WHICH BROKE IT -->
                <div v-for="person in filteredPeople | sortedPeople">
                    <div class="card mb-4" :class="person.has_summative_past_due ? 'alert-warning' : ''">
                        <div class="card-body row" >
                            <div class="col">
                                <h4 class="card-title" v-bind:person='person.full_name'><a v-bind:href="'{% url 'commonground:index' %}' + 'users/' + person.id">[[ person.full_name ]]</a></h4>
                                <p v-if="person.active_summative" class="card-text">
                                    Active Summative Due Date: [[ person.active_summative.due_date ]]
                                    <span v-show="!person.active_summative.past_due" v-bind:past_due='person.active_summative.past_due' class="badge badge-success">[[ person.active_summative.due_date_status ]]</span>
                                    <span v-show="person.active_summative.past_due" class="badge badge-danger">[[ person.active_summative.due_date_status ]]</span>
                                    <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                                        <li class="list-group-item justify-content-between align-items-center" v-for="summary in person.summative_evaluations_summary">
                                            <span class="badge badge-secondary badge-pill">[[summary.evaluation_type__count]]</span> [[ summary.evaluation_type__name ]]
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </p>
                                <p v-if="!person.active_summative" class="card-text">
                                    No Active Unlocked Summatives
                                </p>
                                <a v-if="person.active_summative" :href="person.active_summative.absolute_url" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="far fa-edit"></i> View / Edit Active Summative</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-auto float-right text-right">
                                <p class="h5">
                                    [[ person.base_location ]]
                                    <div v-if="person.multiple_locations" class="small text-muted"><i class="fal fa-info-circle"></i> User has multiple locations</div>
                                </p>
                                <p class="h5">
                                    [[ person.assignment_job ]]
                                    <div v-if="person.multiple_jobs" class="small text-muted"> <i class="fal fa-info-circle"></i> User has multiple jobs</div>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    <!-- END OF VUE -->
    </div>
```

The actual Vue code looks like this:

```
    <script>
        const app = new Vue({
            delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
            el: '#app',
            data: {
                people: [],
                people_count: 0,
                search_term: "",
                sort_filter: "",
            },
            computed: {
                filteredPeople:function()
                {
                    var search = this.search_term.toLowerCase();
                    return this.people.filter(function(person){
                        return Object.values(person).some( val => String(val).toLowerCase().includes(search))
                    })
                },
                sortedPeople:function()
                {
                    var sort_filter = this.sort_filter.toLowerCase();
                    console.log('triggered')
                    return this.people.filter(function(person){
                        return Object.values(person).some( val => String(val).toLowerCase().includes(sort_filter))
                    })
                },
            },
            async created () {
                var response = await fetch("{% url 'user-list' %}");
                this.people = await response.json();
                this.people_count = await this.people.length
            }
        })
    </script>
```

Fairly new to Vue, but I am building this to learn. All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the simple sample I made: [Link](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

```js
    filteredPeople() {
      return this.people.filter(
        (person) =>
          person.firstname
            .toLowerCase()
            .includes(this.search.toLowerCase().trim()) ||
          person.lastname
            .toLowerCase()
            .includes(this.search.toLowerCase().trim())
      );
    },
    sortedPeople() {
      return this.filteredPeople.sort((a, b) =>
        a[this.sortby].localeCompare(b[this.sortby])
      );
    },
```

---

Added asc/dec order: [Link](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

```js
sortedPeople() {
      return this.filteredPeople.sort((a, b) =>
        (this.sort == 'asc') ? a[this.sortby].localeCompare(b[this.sortby]) : b[this.sortby].localeCompare(a[this.sortby])
      );
    },
```

Comment: That is a perfect example. Thank you! If I wanted to include a secondary option (for ascending/descending) are there any particular documents you may recommend?

Comment: I have added a simple example :)